# Reverse geocode different road between public osm database and local database

Tags: openstreetmap

I have a problem with the result of reverse geocoding.
I have created a local instance of openstreet with an Italy OSM database downloaded from geofabrik. The local instance daily updates the database.
When I search an address with public request:

https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/reverse?format=xml&lat=41.9189&lon=12.52001&zoom=18&accept-language=it

The result of road is: "Viale Ventuno Aprile"

But when I call my local instance with the same request the result of road is different.
Why?

Comment: Offtopic for StackOverflow since this is not a programming question. Try asking at http://help.openstreetmap.org/ or http://gis.stackexchange.com/ instead.

Comment: New question here: https://help.openstreetmap.org/questions/69672/reverse-geocode-different-result-between-public-osm-database-and-local-database